# Canon MP780 support, and borderless printing, in Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks?

Tags: macos, printing, driver, canon

Has anyone got their Canon Pixma MP780 to print borderless in Mavericks?

Its support was removed after the CanonPrinterDrivers2.8 (as of writing we are on 2.12). I keep the 2.8 drivers and they worked well with 10.7, 10.8, and now 10.9 (mostly work). However in 10.9 the borderless printing is no longer working. I tried printing from several apps and I just cannot get borderless to work.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: My interim solution is to run VMware Fusion with a Mac OS X 10.8 guest, install the drivers on that, and share the printer out from the guest.